# Resharper shortcuts for new file template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I am used to create new files in Visual Studio/Resharper with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd> for class, <kbd>S</kbd> for struct, <kbd>T</kbd> for test etc.
(this is the same as the menu `Resharper`/`Edit`/`New From template`)

The last step stopped working when I updated to Resharper 9.

Is there a way to restore the old behaviour or is there a new shortcut available.

I tried to rename the template &Class but it didn't help.

Comment: I was just wondering this myself.

Comment: Give Solution Explorer focus (where you want the new file) and type `alt-insert`.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio with ReSharper 9.0+:

> Tools > Options > (Sidebar) Environment > Keyboard

Then:

> Show commands containing:

```
resharper.resharper_template
```

These are the templates listed in the `New from Template` dynamic menu. By default, `Class` is the first template in this list (`Template00`). To assign a shortcut key to the first template in the list:

1. In this location, highlight `ReSharper.ReSharper_Template00`.
2. Choose an option under `Use new shortcut in:` (I chose `Solution Explorer`).
3. Use the `Press shortcut keys:` to assign a shortcut key combination and click `Assign` to save it.

Answer (score 2):

in 2017 version 
 use the Ctrl+Alt+Insert keyboard shortcut -> choose class -> to insert a class

ref: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/Templates__Applying_Templates__Creating_Files_from_Templates.html